# Calling a Powershell script with the "-command" parameter instead of "-file"

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-line-arguments

What is the difference between calling a powershell script like this:

```
powershell.exe -file "myfile.ps1"
```

and like this (which also works):

```
powershell.exe -command "myfile.ps1"
```

thanks, robert

Comment: Did you take a look at `powershell.exe -?` help? It explains the main differences. If you are interested in subtle differences then this is not clear from the question.

Comment: Of course i looked into the help. I was suprised "-command" even works in the way i wrote above, because it is not documented. The question is, is there any difference in how the script is executed.
For example it seems, terminating errors do not work as expected in the second case. But i am not sure. I can not ask any more detailed because i dont know any more details. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`powershell.exe -file "myfile.ps1"` — that means: start PowerShell and execute file `myfile.ps1` (file name considered to be relative to current directory) in global scope.
`powershell.exe -command "myfile.ps1"` — that means: start PowerShell and execute command `myfile.ps1`, and PowerShell allows you to execute script files by typing their names in command line.

**Differences:**

1. In absence of dot source operator `. myfile.ps1` PowerShell create new scope when command resolved to be script file.
2. PowerShell does not look in current directory as source of commands. So if file `myfile.ps1` resides in current directory, and current directory not in `PATH` environment variable, then PowerShell fail to find `myfile.ps1` command.
3. If file `myfile.ps1` can be found in any directory mentioned in `PATH` environment variable before current directory, then `myfile.ps1` command will be resolved to that file rather then to file `myfile.ps1` in current directory.
4. You can create alias in you profile like `New-Alias myfile.ps1 DoSomethingElse`, and in this case `myfile.ps1` command will be considered as reference to that alias rather then to `myfile.ps1` file.

Answer (score 4):

Running `powershell.exe -File` will return the exit code set by the script, whereas running `powershell.exe -Command` will return 1 if the script terminated with a non-zero exit code, or 0 otherwise.

```
C:\>type "C:\path\to\test.ps1"
exit 5

C:\>powershell.exe -command "C:\path\to\test.ps1"

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\>powershell.exe -file "C:\path\to\test.ps1"

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
5
```

Comment: Added this to [PowerShellTraps](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps) as *Exit-code-5-with-File-1-with-Command*